# unable to deploy two application simulteneously on wildfly using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I am new to the Jboss server. 
I am using wildfly for hot code deployment. And have two dynamic web projects. 
I can able to deploy and use hot deployment feature when i deploy one app at a time. 
But when i add two DWPs to server and start it, deployment is failing for both application. Is there any setting that we need to enable to allow multiple projects?
I am using eclipse keplar, java 7, jboss 8.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem to deploy on a standard wildfly many ear/war-files.
It is possible that you copy and pasted the project ? In this case the web-context could be on both projects the same.

After you start your wildfly you should see two files like .war.failed or
-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.failed

could you post the error messages?